# Oracle Statement for outer join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

### Module Table

- ModuleID
- ModuleData
- ModuleSectionID

### UserProfile Table

- UserProfileID
- UserID
- ModuleID

I need to join the two tables together, but the UserProfile table won't necessary be present for each Module entry. I will be passed the two variables ModuleSectionID, and UserID. These will help narrow down results in the final set.

The desired result should something like this

```
M.ModuleID, M.ModuleData, M.ModuleSection, U.UserProfileID, U.UserID, U.ModuleID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13         "DataData"     3                1                132       13
12         "Data2Data2"   3                Null             Null      Null
15         "Data3Data3"   3                3                132       15
```

Comment: Isn't this a typical outer join problem ? What do you need help with ?

Comment: Yes it is, but I'm not that crafty with Oracle, more of a MSSQL person, so my syntax was having problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT M.ModuleID, M.ModuleData, M.ModuleSectionID, U.UserProfileID, U.UserID, U.ModuleID
    FROM Module m, UserProfile u 
 WHERE M.ModuleSctionID = <MODULE_SECTIONID_PARAMETER>
 AND M.ModuleID = U.ModuleID(+)
 AND <USER_ID_PARAMETER> = U.UserID (+)
```

Comment: Yup this works. Apparently I Missed the (+) operator on the userid. Thanks.

Comment: @Seth Duncan: The (+) operator is Oracle specific syntax that's been superceded by ANSI-92 syntax.  The (+) operator should be considered deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
   SELECT m.moduleid,
          m.moduledata,
          m.modulesection,
          up.upserprofileid,
          up.userid, 
          up.moduleid
     FROM MODULE m
LEFT JOIN USERPROFILE up ON up.moduleid = m.moduleid
                        AND up.userid = IN_USERID
    WHERE m.modulesection = IN_MODULESECTIONID
```

The `IN_USERID` and `IN_MODULESECTIONID` represent the variables you want to supply to the query.

Comment: Is Left Join an operator in Oracle (I know it is in MSSQL my chosen sql language) but yeah that is how you would do it in MSSQL for sure.

Comment: @Seth Duncan: LEFT JOIN (also RIGHT JOIN -- the OUTER keyword is optional) is ANSI-92 standard -- supported Oracle 9i+, MySQL, SQL Server...

Comment: P.S. Thanks for cleaning up my question, much clearer with proper formatting.

Comment: Good to know, all the initial results on Google pointed at the (+) operator which I did not have much experience with. Thanks for the lesson.